# Скажите правильно ли я думаю-Матрица c++

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Изначально имел код который выводил матрицу.

Я делал 2 столбца по 3 числа в диапазоне от 1 до 6.

Потом начал экспериментировать что бы посмотреть что будет

Изначально было `int a[N][M]; cin >> a[i][j]; cout << a[i][j];`

Я убрал `[M],[j]`

и в итоге получаются значения

```
2 2 2 
4 4 4
```

Я думаю происходит следующие

```
a[N] = a[2]
i<=3 j<=2
i=1
j=1 Пишу число 1 a[i] = {1 , Место для второго числа }
j=2 Пишу число 2 a[i] = {2 , Место для второго числа } (Число 1 перезаписало в число 2)
i=2 
j=1 Пишу число 3 a[i] = {2,3}
j=2 Пишу число 4 a[i] = {2,4}(Число 3 перезаписало в число 4)

Так как a[i] = a[2] Но a[2]={2,4}
То i=3 не выполнится (массив уже полный)
```

Ну и дальше

```
i<=2 j<=3 a[2] = {2,4}
i=1 (взяли первый элемент массива)
j=1 2
j=2 2
j=3 2
i=2 (взяли 2 элемент массива)
j=1 4
j=2 4
j=3 4
```

**Верно или я себе просто картинку подогнал что бы все сходилось?**

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "RUS");
int i,j,N,M;
cout << "Введите количество строк матрицы " << endl;
cin >> N;
cout << "Введите количество столбцов матрицы" << endl;
cin >> M;
int a[N];
cout << "Введите числа матрицы" << endl;
for (i=1;i<=M;i++){
   for(j=1;j<=N;j++){
       cin >> a[i];
   }
}
cout << "Ваша матрица \n" ;
for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
   for(j=1;j<=M;j++){
       cout << a[i] <<"\t";
   }
           cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы знаете как индексируются массивы в с++? 1ый элемент имеет индекс 0! Но вы в любом случае в 1ом цикле можете выйти за границы, у вас i изменяется до М, тогда как размер массива определяется как N. И да, посколько это не константа времени компиляции, int a[N]; не скомпилируется

Answer (score 1):

Даже если у вас скомпилируется GNUсное :) `int a[N];`, то вы все равно делаете ерунду - просто переписываете одни и те же элементы массива...

Опустим то, что `M` и `N` могут быть разными и вы можете выскочить за границы массива. И даже то, что элементы массива нумеруются с 0.

Вот только если все это опустить и не обращать внимания - то да, вот тут

```
for (i=1;i<=M;i++){
   for(j=1;j<=N;j++){
       cin >> a[i];
   }
}
```

вы просто `N` раз переписываете `a[i]` элемент, затирая то, что было введено ранее.

А тут

```
for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
   for(j=1;j<=M;j++){
       cout << a[i] <<"\t";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

вы выводите

```
a[1]  a[1]  a[1]  ... (M раз)
a[2]  a[2]  a[2]  ... (M раз)
a[3]  a[3]  a[3]  ... (M раз)
....
a[N]  a[N]  a[N]  ... (M раз)
```

(Напомню еще раз - в вашем массиве **нет** элемента `a[N]`).